# iframe not displaying (local) file

Tags: wordpress, iframe, filenames, src

I have a html file(mySheet.html) that I uploaded onto my Wordpress site. I would like to display this html file on a page, let's say page1. This is the code of page1:

```
<div>
<iframe src="mySheet.html"> </iframe>
</div>
```

When I load page1, I get this error message:
"File Not Found"

I understand that I need to have mySheet.html in the right directory or specify the relative path correctly.

I need help with this.
Thanks!